# Elastic Search - Failed to parse query

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am using python-elasticsearch client - [elasticsearch.py](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html) and elastic search fails to parse query when I try to update a document using `update_by_query` method.

My update body is as follows:

```
{
  'script': {
    'inline': 'ctx._source.viewers += info',
    'params': {
      'info': {
        'time': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 7, 18, 8, 50),
        'viewer': 'abc@xyz.com'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Elastic Search is called as follows::

```
update = es.update_by_query(index=index_el,
                            doc_type='1',
                            q='delivery_reference_id:' + str(cam_id) +'',
                            body=doc)
```

A sample value for `cam_id` is:

```
CAM_10_DATA_4_2017-03-07 18:02:07
```

Internally, the following query is formed::

`http://127.0.0.1:9200/user_tracker/1/_update_by_query?q=delivery_reference_id%3ACAM_10_DATA_4_2017-03-07+18%3A02%3A07`

The error received is as follows:

```
TransportError(400, 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'Failed to parse query [delivery_reference_id:CAM_10_DATA_4_2017-03-07 18:02:07]')
```

The full error log is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\catch\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python34\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 42, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\catch\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python34\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\catch\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python34\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\catch\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python34\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\catch\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python34\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 483, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 443, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\catch\PycharmProjects\myproject\myproj\apis\views.py", line 516, in get
    viewer=viewer_email)
  File "C:\Users\catch\PycharmProjects\myproject\myproj\apis\views.py", line 541, in update_track_info
    doc=doc)
  File "C:\Users\catch\PycharmProjects\myproject\myproj\apis\views.py", line 553, in es_update
    body=doc)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\client\utils.py", line 73, in _wrapped
    return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\client\__init__.py", line 680, in update_by_query
    doc_type, '_update_by_query'), params=params, body=body)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\transport.py", line 318, in perform_request
    status, headers, data = connection.perform_request(method, url, params, body, ignore=ignore, timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\connection\http_urllib3.py", line 128, in perform_request
    self._raise_error(response.status, raw_data)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\connection\base.py", line 122, in _raise_error
    raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(status_code, error_message, additional_info)
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: TransportError(400, 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'Failed to parse query [delivery_reference_id:CAM_10_DATA_4_2017-03-07 18:02:07]')
```

Would be nice if someone figured it out. Let me know if more info is needed.

Appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What ES version are you using?

Comment: Elastic Search Version: 5.2.0

Answer (score 1):

I think your query syntax is not up to date.  I had good results with the following syntax:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "match": { "MYFIELD": "myoldvalue" } }
      ]
    }
  },
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.MYFIELD = \"mynewvalue\"",
    "lang": "painless"
  }
}
```

HTH :)

Comment: How would I make the above request using python-elasticsearch client?

Comment: Just replace the body you supplied above with this

Comment: I tried with:

`{
  'script': {
    'inline': 'ctx._source.viewers += info',
    'params': {
      'info': {
        'viewer': 'divij.sehgaal7@gmail.com',
        'time': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 7, 18, 49, 23)
      }
    }
  },
  'query': {
    'bo ol': {
      'must': [
        {
          'match': {
            'delivery_reference_id': '"CAM_10_DATA_4_2017-03-07 18:02:07"'
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}`
and get the following error:
`elasticsearch.exceptions.TransportError: TransportError(500, 'script_exception', 'compile error')`

Comment: @Divij Sehgal did you find a solution? I'm having the same problem

Comment: @gal007 Its been long and its hard to remember exactly what I did, but If I can remember correctly, I think Alfe 's solution worked.

Comment: @gal007 Currently, you could check the official docs for any changes in this area and see if that works.

Comment: The problem is official docs are not always updated :( But I changed "inline" for  "source" and it worked :)